# The function call includes an invalid number of repeating parameters. Repeating parameters must be included in full sets

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, landing-page

I have a landing page that allows you to create a new record in SFMC when I valid the information or I click on the button valid I have this error message:

> **The function call includes an invalid number of repeating parameters. Repeating parameters must be included in full sets**

**this is my code:**

```
set @sexe = RequestParameter("GENDER")
set @firstname = RequestParameter("FIRSTNAME")
set @lastname = RequestParameter("SURNAME")
set @email = RequestParameter("EMAIL")
set @date= RequestParameter("BIRTHDATE")
set @tel = RequestParameter("PHONENUMBER")

IF TAG_AFFILIATE= 'BE' THEN
  set @langue = RequestParameter("PREFERRED_LANGUAGE") 
ENDIF

set @day = Substring(@date,1,2)
set @month = Substring(@date,4,2)
set @year = Substring(@date,7,4)  
set @UID = MD5(@email)

IF TAG_AFFILIATE == 'BE' THEN
  (UPSERTDATA("CUSTOMER_LOT_7","UID_TARGET",@UID, "DateSent",NOW(), "FIRSTNAME", @firstname, "SURNAME", @lastname, "EMAIL", @email, "PHONENUMBER",@tel, "GENDER", @sexe, "PREFERRED_LANGUAGE", @langue, "BIRTHDATE", @date)) 
else
  (UPSERTDATA("CUSTOMER_LOT_7","UID_TARGET",@UID, "DateSent",NOW(),"FIRSTNAME", @firstname, "SURNAME", @lastname, "EMAIL", @email, "PHONENUMBER",@tel, "GENDER", @sexe, "BIRTHDATE", @date))
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the number of filter columns to insert or update (see **n**)

```
(UPSERTDATA("CUSTOMER_LOT_7", n, "UID_TARGET",@UID, "DateSent",NOW(), "FIRSTNAME", @firstname, "SURNAME", @lastname, "EMAIL", @email, "PHONENUMBER",@tel, "GENDER", @sexe, "PREFERRED_LANGUAGE", @langue, "BIRTHDATE", @date))
```

Is there a reason for the surrounding parentheses?

Comment: surrounding parentheses is not required, the function works irrespective of it.

Comment: Thank you for your help I didn't see it thank you :)